# Questions asks to work with pointers to return portion of string

Tags: c, pointers, arithmetic-expressions

```
int main (void)
{
char c[] = "KATEWINCE";
char *p =c;
printf("%s", p+p[3]-p[1]) ;
return (0);
}
```

The output is WINCE but I don't get how the code is working, please explain.

Comment: Assuming ASCII encoding of your characters, look up the values ASCII values of the characters `p[3]` and `p[1]`. Then it's plain *pointer arithmetic*.

Comment: I also recommend you take some squared paper, write each letter in the array `c` in its own square, and then make an arrow pointing to the first character. This arrow is the pointer `p`. Then add `p[3]` squares and make the arrow point to that square. Then subtract `p[1]` and again redraw the arrow. That might help you understand what's going on.

Comment: `p+p[3]-p[1]` is `p + 'E' - 'A'` and assuming the letter coding is sequential that is `p + 4` which is where `"WINCE"` begins.

Comment: Is this an assignment you were given in a class you're taking?  It's a terrible, meaningless problem.  Pointer arithmetic is perfectly reasonable; we do it all the time.  It's occasionally meaningful (and it's not wrong) to subtract the values of two characters.  But it's very hard to think of a realistic reason why you would subtract the values of two characters, then use the difference to do pointer arithmetic like this.  If you understand why `printf("%s", p+4)` prints "WINCE", you understand the essential property of pointer arithmetic.  The character subtraction is just obfuscation.

Comment: Yes I got it... Thanks for help, and yes it was a part of assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You assigned 0x45 to `c[3]`/`p[3]`.<sup>[1]</sup>

You assigned 0x41 to `c[1]`/`p[1]`.<sup>[1]</sup>

So `p + p[3] - p[1]` is equivalent to `p + 0x45 - 0x41`.

This attempts to advance `p` by 0x45 elements. This is undefined behaviour. You can advance a pointer to the position immediately following the object to which it points, but no further. `c` is simply not that large.

But let's say `c` was far larger. You would see the same result as you posted here.

`p` is advanced by 0x45 elements, then reversed by 0x41 elements. The net result is that `p` is advanced by 4 elements. And that's exactly what we see.

---

1. Assuming an ASCII-based machine.